# Function not returning a Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm have been struggling to find a way add a new post(kind of) to the screen with each button click. I'm new react and doesn't really know a lot. the function does work and console.log() but doesn't return a Post component;

```
export default class Extra extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            val :'',
            posts: []
        }
    }

    handlePost = () => {
        const newPost = <Post status = "Status" about = "This post is about React"></Post>;
        this.state.posts.push(newPost);
        console.log(this.state.posts.length);
        return (this.state.posts[this.state.posts[this.state.posts.length-1]]);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>

                <button onClick = {this.handlePost}className = "fixed">Post</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const Post = ({ status, about }) => {
    return(
        <div className = "UI">
            <h2>{status}</h2><hr/><br/>
            <p>{about}</p>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Post;
```

Comment: There are many thing wrong with your code. First is you shouldn't mutate state using this.state you should use this.SetState.

Comment: can you specify where

Comment: handle post method

Comment: you mean something like this,         this.setState({posts: this.state.posts.push(newPost)})

Comment: You are again mutating old state. Which is wrong. see my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
export default class Extra extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            val :'',
            posts: []
        }
    }

    handlePost = () => {
        const newPost = <Post status = "Status" about = "This post is about React"></Post>;
        this.setState({posts:[...this.state.posts,newPost]});
        console.log(this.state.posts.length);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>

                <button onClick = {this.handlePost}className = "fixed">Post</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const Post = ({ status, about }) => {
    return(
        <div className = "UI">
            <h2>{status}</h2><hr/><br/>
            <p>{about}</p>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Post;
```

Comment: thanks Arora, can you tell me what those 3 dots mean( in th handlePost function)

Comment: it's a spread operator see more on mdn(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)